# Why do I get Instance name after event.target, instead of the Sprite name?

Tags: actionscript-3, instance, addeventlistener

I done same thing in two classes. I can't see I done something different, but must have. Because in one I get "Instance54" or something after click when I use trace(event.target) instead of the Spritename which I got in a another class. Now I have maked a workaround, but can someone explain when eventlisteners get instance-name instead of the Sprite-name?

```
private var fly:Sprite = new Sprite;
private var flyArea:Sprite = new Sprite;
```

...

```
public function()
{
fly.addChild(new R.fly);
flyArea.addChild(new R.bg);
flyArea.addChild(fly);
fly.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,flyClick, false, 0, true);
```

...

```
private function changeFlikOrder(event:MouseEvent):void
trace (event.target);
```

Comment: Vesper answer is correct. The code that you have posted must be showing the Instance54. Can you post the other code as well where spriteName is being shown

Answer (score 1):

In all the years I have been doing Flash I have never needed to rely on the name property. You should be setting a var to any objects you create and using that to ref your objects:

```
// not sure why you don't have () in your example but here goes
fly.addChild(new R.fly());
```

but there is no ref to R.fly now, if you did:

```
var myFly:YourTypeHere = new R.fly();
fly.addChild(myFly);
```

Now you can just reference myFly anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't supply the "name" property to your object after you create it, then it receives an auto-generated name "instance"+number. Most likely it's made for `getChildByName()` to be certain that only one child has that particular name. You implicitely give names to instances when you edit their attributes in graphical designer of Flash CS, so I expect the object that returns "Sprite-name" is the pre-placed one.